# Date won't save in Mysql when I use jQuery date picker in jsp

Tags: jquery, mysql, date, jsp, datepicker

I need to disable the previous dates as well so jQuery is this..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#dueDate").datepicker({
                dateformat : 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                minDate: 0
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Jsp

```
<input type="date" id="dueDate" name="dueDate">
```

The type for the dueDate is `DATE` in MySql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client Side : Change the Input type to text

Server Side : Convert String -->Util Date -->Sql Date-->insert

Try This

Client Side:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#dueDate").datepicker({
                dateformat : 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                autoclose: true,
                minDate: 0
            });
        });
    </script>


  <body>
     <form action="dueDate">
       Date:  <input type="text" id="dueDate" name="dueDate">
         <input type="submit">
     </form>
  <body>
```

Server Side:

```
            String dueDate = request.getParameter("dueDate");

            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            java.util.Date utilDate = formatter.parse(dueDate);

            java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());

            Connection con = DBConn.getConn();

            PreparedStatement psmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO STACKISSUE(dateVal)VALUES(?)");
            psmt.setDate(1, sqlDate);
            psmt.executeUpdate();
            psmt.close();
            con.close();
```

Comment: Cheers!! Keep Coding.